# what software is used by Google and others that posts custom ads for different users

Tags: facebook

what software is used by Google and others that posts custom ads for different users, but doesn't reveal user's ID to the advertiser?

the software let's advertisers target specific types of consumers without giving away their personal identification information

Can any website owner get that software?

Answer (score 0):

These are most certainly in-house proprietary solutions.